# How to calculate load time of Asp.net page using Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I am developing one web application in that I want to check load time of each and every page or controls load time..


How much time taken to load whole page contents?

I want to calculate asp.net page load Time in Micro second/Second,

How can I know using Javascript/Jquery ?

Comment: are you loading the page through ajax? if the page you want to time is the main page in the browser then i suppose it cannot be done, but if you want to see how long it takes to load a script inside a frame or from ajax, then it's possible

Comment: @galchen no I used jquery functions to load page using webservice... there is not ajaxtoolkit used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following script help you;

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
//calculate the time before calling the function in window.onload
beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();
function pageloadingtime()
{

     //calculate the current time in afterload 
    afterload = (new Date()).getTime();
     // now use the beforeload and afterload to calculate the seconds
    secondes = (afterload-beforeload)/1000;
     // If necessary update in window.status
    window.status='You Page Load took  ' + secondes + ' seconde(s).';
     // Place the seconds in the innerHTML to show the results
    document.getElementById("loadingtime").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>(You Page Load took " + secondes + " seconde(s).)</font>";

}

window.onload = pageloadingtime;
</SCRIPT>
```

Ref from : http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1908.htm

or

If you just want to check the time make use of **Firebug** of firefox which display excution time. 
Something like this [image]

Comment: Firebug. Definitely Firebug (or Chrome's equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Developed by the good people at stackoverflow - handy little profiling tool - may work for you:

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/